# VSTS Task Creation : Required field missing

Tags: c#, json, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create task in `VSTS`, but I am getting the below *error*.

> TF401320: Rule Error for field Task Type. Error code: Required, HasValues, LimitedToValues, AllowsOldValue, InvalidEmpty.

From `Exception` it is clear that I am missing a required field which is `Task Type`. Now I am not able to find the field path for `Task Type`. Can anyone help me with this.

Below is the code I am writing to add a task :

```
string discipline = "Research Task";

if (taskDesc.Key.Contains("Configuration"))
{
    discipline = "Dev Task";
}
if (taskDesc.Key.Contains("Validation"))
{
    discipline = "Quality Task";
}

var workitemtype = "Task";
var document = new JsonPatchDocument();
document.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Discipline",
        Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
        Value = discipline
    });
document.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Path = "/fields/System.Title",
        Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
        Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", porIDText, taskDesc.Key)
    });
document.Add(new JsonPatchOperation()
{
    Path = "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
    Value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AreaPath"]
});
document.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Path = "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
        Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
        Value = "<name>"
    });
document.Add(
    new JsonPatchOperation()
    {
        Path = "/fields/System.Description",
        Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
        Value = taskDesc.Value
    });
var wi = client.CreateWorkItemAsync(
document,
teamProjectName,
workitemtype).Result;
```

Comment: Change paths to `//` or add `@` in front for proper path handeling

Comment: with the same format i am able to create scenario in vsts but surely i will follow what you said.

Comment: @arias_JC You are thinking backwards it is `\ ` that needs escaping or a `@`. The OP is using `/` which does not need escaping.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain true that :)

Comment: What kind of object is `taskDesc`

Comment: its a `Dictionary`. I am iterating through a foreach loop like this `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> taskDesc in taskNamesAndDescriptions)
                {.........}` The complete code is enclosed in these braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add Task Type field to Task work item, but don’t add to the layout.

[image]

You can check fields of Task work item in Web Access (Go to collection page > Settings >Process >Select template >Work Item Types >Task >Fields) or through [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-item-types#get-a-work-item-type).

Setting value of Task Type field:

Code:

```
    document.Add(
        new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json.JsonPatchOperation()
        {
            Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.TaskType",
            Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
            Value = "Type1"
        });
```